# Add a ListView Into a SlidingDrawer?

Tags: android, listview, slidingdrawer

How do I inflate a ListView into a SlidingDrawer?  Thnx for the input.

The main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<WebView android:id="@+id/webView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</WebView>

<include android:id="@+id/windowTitle" layout="@layout/window_title" />
<include android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer" layout="@layout/sliding_drawer" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The Drawer XML:

```
<SlidingDrawer android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer" android:handle="@+id/handle" android:content="@+id/content"
android:allowSingleTap="false">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dip" android:background="@drawable/gradient2">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/handleGrip" android:src="@drawable/handle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView android:id="@+id/content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do something like this.

```
<SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/drawer" android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:content="@+id/content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Below there is a list view." />

        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/listview_"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent" 
            android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView android:id="@id/handle" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/icon" />

</SlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: Thnx for the link - I had been searching all-over the net for this.

Comment: @camelCaser: I'm not sure if you meant to award the bounty when acepting this answer or not, but just in case, as it's a common mistake to believe that accepting an answer awards a bounty.  It doesn't.  To award it you have to click the bounty icon (50), next to the check by the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had done so. Oh, I did - Have to wait 4 more hrs.;